# What's the difference between transform vs applymap for pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

While the [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) function on DataFrame operates element-wise, the [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) function seems to achieve the same thing except claiming to return a like-indexed DataFrame.

Questions:

1. Is there any use case where one of them works and the other doesn't?
2. Does one have better performance than the other?
3. What's a like-indexed DataFrame stated in the documentation?

Answer (score 16):

Different use cases.  When comparing them, it is useful to bring up `apply` and `agg` as well.

**Setup**

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(6, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

df

   A  B  C  D
0  0  2  7  3
1  8  7  0  6
2  8  6  0  2
3  0  4  9  7
4  3  2  4  3
5  3  6  7  7
```

---

**`pd.DataFrame.applymap`**
This takes a function and returns a new dataframe with the results of that function being applied to the value in each cell and replacing the value of the cell with the result.

```
df.applymap(lambda x: str(x) * x)

          A        B          C        D
0                 22    7777777      333
1  88888888  7777777              666666
2  88888888   666666                  22
3               4444  999999999  7777777
4       333       22       4444      333
5       333   666666    7777777  7777777
```

---

**`pd.DataFrame.agg`**
Takes one or more functions.  Each function is expected to be an aggregation function.  Meaning each function is applied to each column and is expected to return a single value that replaces the entire column.  Examples would be `'mean'` or `'max'`.  Both of those take a set of data and return a scalar.

```
df.agg('mean')

A    3.666667
B    4.500000
C    4.500000
D    4.666667
dtype: float64
```

Or

```
df.agg(['mean', 'std', 'first', 'min'])

             A         B         C         D
mean  3.666667  4.500000  4.500000  4.666667
std   3.614784  2.167948  3.834058  2.250926
min   0.000000  2.000000  0.000000  2.000000
```

---

**`pd.DataFrame.transform`**
Takes one function that is expected to be applied to a column and return a column of equal size.

```
df.transform(lambda x: x / x.std())

          A         B         C         D
0  0.000000  0.922531  1.825742  1.332785
1  2.213133  3.228859  0.000000  2.665570
2  2.213133  2.767594  0.000000  0.888523
3  0.000000  1.845062  2.347382  3.109832
4  0.829925  0.922531  1.043281  1.332785
5  0.829925  2.767594  1.825742  3.109832
```

---

**`pd.DataFrame.apply`**
pandas attempts to figure out if `apply` is reducing the dimensionality of the column it was operating on (aka, aggregation) or if it is transforming the column into another column of equal size.  When it figures it out, it runs the remainder of the operation as if it were an aggregation or transform procedure.

```
df.apply('mean')

A    3.666667
B    4.500000
C    4.500000
D    4.666667
dtype: float64
```

Or

```
df.apply(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std())

          A         B         C         D
0 -1.014353 -1.153164  0.652051 -0.740436
1  1.198781  1.153164 -1.173691  0.592349
2  1.198781  0.691898 -1.173691 -1.184698
3 -1.014353 -0.230633  1.173691  1.036611
4 -0.184428 -1.153164 -0.130410 -0.740436
5 -0.184428  0.691898  0.652051  1.036611
```

Comment: Thanks but you didn't answer my questions

Comment: @darcyq applymap is typically slow. Though it has gotten better the last several versions. See my examples and try to figure out the answers to your other questions.

Comment: Appreciate your answer @piRSquared. I actually read your answer in the pandas documentation before. I can obviously read the source code, but before I spend time doing that, I wanna see if anyone knows it off the top of her head.

Comment: @darcyq This user has spent a lot of time answering your questions. In fact, your question should be _closed_ on the grounds of being too broad. The answer to all your questions is _obviously_ that _it depends_. It depends on the data, it depends on the context, the version, your system, _everything_. You can't expect a one-fits-all answer to this kind of question. To top it off, you downvoted this answer. Why would you do that?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ **A)** I did appreciate his answer, it's a long answer but it's pretty much the same as https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#aggregation-api. **B)** More importantly it doesn't answer my question. **C)** I'm asking the difference between two pandas functions (as the subject says). One can dig into the source code and find out the answer as I mentioned. I really don't think it's a broad question.

Comment: @darcyq Do you really need to know how the source code is written to understand how the functions differ? This answer explains perfectly how those two functions work. One works on a series, the other works on individual cells. If you must really see the source code, it is freely available on GitHub so [knock yourself out](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L4792).

Comment: What function can be used to transform all ROWS into a new column? I want to apply a function that takes an entire row and returns a single value.

Comment: @SimonHessner `df.apply(lambda row: row.count(), axis=1)`

Answer (score 6):

> What's meant by `.transform()` returns a like-indexed DataFrame stated in the documentation?

That means `.transform()` applies a function to every value (or a group, once preceded by `groupby`) in the DataFrame and returns another DataFrame with the same length as the input, so to emphasize:  it keeps the input index labels in the output.

> Is there any use case where one of applymap/transform and the other doesn't?

Sure. Here are some examples:

## 1) applymap    Vs    transform

Since `applymap` performs on all elements of a DataFrame, you can't perform `applymap` on a Series:

```
df['Quantity'].transform(lambda x: x+10) # successful
df['Quantity'].apply(lambda x: x+10) # successful
df['Quantity'].applymap(lambda x: x+10) # gives AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'

# unless you cast it to DataFrame:
pd.DataFrame(df['Quantity']).applymap(lambda x: x+10) # successful
```

Another important difference is that despite `.applymap()` which operates element-wise, `.transform()` can perform group-wise operations, referred to in the next part.

Moreover, `applymap` cannot be preceded by `groupby`.

## 2) apply    Vs    transform

`apply` and `transform` can be interchangeable as long as you perform them on DataFrame column(s). Here is a simple example:

```
# imagine the following DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Label': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C'],
                   'Values': [0,1,2,3,4],
                   'Quantity': [5,6,7,8,9]}, index = list('VWXYZ'))


    Label   Quantity   Values
---------------------------------
V    A         5         0
W    B         6         1
X    C         7         2
Y    A         8         3
Z    C         9         4


df.loc[:, ['Quantity', 'Values']].apply(lambda x: x+10)
df.loc[:, ['Quantity', 'Values']].transform(lambda x: x+10)
# both of them give the following same result:

    Quantity   Values
-------------------------
V    15          10
W    16          11
X    17          12
Y    18          13
Z    19          14
```

The main difference emerges once they follow a `groupby` operation. For instance:

```
label_grouping = df.groupby('Label')
label_grouping.apply(lambda x: x.mean())
# output:

      Quantity   Values
Label
-----------------------
A       6.5       1.5
B       6.0       1.0
C       8.0       3.0

label_grouping.transform(lambda x: x.mean())
# see how `transform` could manage to keeps the input index labels in the output
# output:

    Quantity   Values
------------------------
V     6.5       1.5
W     6.0       1.0
X     8.0       3.0
Y     6.5       1.5
Z     8.0       3.0
```

The above example clearly shows how `transform` can retain input DataFrame indexes; So to get the better of this exclusive feature, the following short example tries to clarify how to benefit from this alignment of the indexes between the input and output of the `transform` operation, by calculating the percentage of order total that each product represents:

```
df_sales = pd.DataFrame({'OrderID': [1001,1001,1001,1002,1002],
                         'Product': ['p1','p2','p3','p1','p4'],
                         'Quantity': [30,20,70,160,40]})


    OrderID   Product   Quantity
-----------------------------------
0    1001       p1        30
1    1001       p2        20
2    1001       p3        70
3    1002       p1        160
4    1002       p4        40


df_sales['total_per_order'] = df_sales.groupby(['OrderID'])['Quantity'].transform(lambda x: x.sum()) 
df_sales['pct_of_order'] = df_sales['Quantity'] / df_sales['total_per_order']


    OrderID   Product   Quantity   total_per_order   pct_of_order
----------------------------------------------------------------------
0    1001       p1        30           120             0.250000
1    1001       p2        20           120             0.166667
2    1001       p3        70           120             0.583333
3    1002       p1        160          200             0.800000
4    1002       p4        40           200             0.200000
```

It's highly advised to follow this link for a more detailed example: https://pbpython.com/pandas_transform.html

Many aggregation functions are built in directly to the `groupby` object to save you some typing. specifically some of the common ones to benefit from are (prefixed by gb):

- gb.apply
- gb.transform
- gb.filter
- gb.agg
- gb.count
- gb.comsum
- gb.fillna
- ...

Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 3):

I am new Pandas and was trying to find an answer to the same question. I did find this on the Pandas website (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html)

> Since not all functions can be vectorized (accept NumPy arrays and
>   return another array or value), the methods applymap() on DataFrame
>   and analogously map() on Series accept any Python function taking a
>   single value and returning a single value.

I am taking that to mean that functions passed to transform should be vectorized, and the entire series will be passed as an argument to these functions. Functions passed to map (and applymap) do not need to be vectorized, and each element will be passed to the function as map iterates over the series.

Answer (score 0):

```
> df = pd.DataFrame([['europe', 'france', 68],
>                    ['europe', 'russia', 144],
>                    ['asia', 'china', 1398]],
>                   columns=['continent', 'country', 'population'])
> df

  continent country  population
0    europe  france          68
1    europe  russia         144
2      asia   china        1398
```

**applymap**

```
> df[['country', 'population']].set_index('country')
  .applymap(lambda x: 'big' if x > 100 else 'small')

country           
france       small
russia         big
china          big

> df.groupby(['continent'], sort=False)['population'].applymap(max)

AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'applymap'
```

**transform**

```
> df[['country', 'population']].set_index('country')
  .transform(lambda x: 'big' if x > 100 else 'small')

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.

> df.groupby(['continent'], sort=False)['population'].transform(max)

0     144
1     144
2    1398
Name: population, dtype: int64

> df[df.groupby(['continent'], sort=False)['population'].transform(max)
     == df['population']]

  continent country  population
1    europe  russia         144
2      asia   china        1398
```